# Matlab - [h,bins]=hist(data)

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have the histogram shown below:[image]

In order to get the image data, I used this `matlab` command: `[h,bins]=hist(data)`

The output that I got was as follows:

```
h =

   221    20     6     4     1     1     2     0     0     1


bins =

  Columns 1 through 7

    8.2500   24.7500   41.2500   57.7500   74.2500   90.7500  107.2500

  Columns 8 through 10

  123.7500  140.2500  156.7500
```

What does `h` refer to?

Comment: I'm assuming you know what a histogram is, given that you're using the `hist` function. If so, then `h` corresponds to the "counts", ie the number of observations in each bin of the histogram. It is all in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).

Comment: @ Colin T Bowers. Thanks for your reply. But, aren't the `columns' those that represent the number of observations? What is a `bin` in this case? Isn't it the `x-axis` values? Thanks

Comment: @ Nasser M. Abbasi. Do you mean by container the `bins`? What is `bin` in this case? Thanks

Comment: hist distributes the elements of `data` into 10 bins (Matlabs default) centered on the x-axis at the elements in `h`. Use `histc` if it is more natural to specify bin edges instead of centers.

Comment: @nate. So, does `h` represent the `x-axis` values?

Comment: did you read the comments above? (like the first comment 1 by  @Colin T Bowers ?) can you read the numbers that `h` and `bins` have and see how they make sense, like bins is monotonically increasing with the same step size, h is just amplitudes or counts at each bin position,  did you tried to read the documentation???

Comment: So, are `bins` like containers of values on the `x-axis`? In this case, shouldn't we have some range for each `bin`? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

h is the number of elements of data that fall into the respective bin in the histogram.

Comment: Based on the values of `bins` in my question, don't they represent the `frequency` value which is shown on the `y-axis`? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Where "frequency" = number of elements of data falling into the respective bin.

Comment: Why do we see the count in real numbers? Shouldn't they be as `integers` especially we are counting the number of elements?

Comment: Yes, the counts are integers. Look at your vector h. They are all integers. I think you are confusing bins and h. h (in your example) is the vector containing the counts. bins is the center value of each bin (using the scale that appears on the x-axis in your chart).