# What is the meaning of xout in the function [n, xout] = hist(Y)?

Tags: matlab

In the Matlab function [n, xout] = hist(Y), the documentation is not clear on what is the meaning of xout. Are these the center values of the bins, the lower bounds, or upper bounds?

Thanks.

Comment: I am quite confused, there is exactly the same question 4 questions below yours under the tag 'Matlab'. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13487768/1714661) btw.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't see that question. But actually, they are two different questions. Other one asks about h (n in the Matlab documentation notation). I am asking about xout.

Comment: `xout` is a characteristic value of each class. The `bar` plot will give the frequency of the class exactly on such `xout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that xout is the **center value** of each bin in the histogram.

Comment: The Matlab documentation of `hist()` really isn't very clear in this point.

Comment: I agree. Hence, the question. But I tested with some sample data, and it appears to be the center. I would be interested to here a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

**xout** is the center value of each bin in the histogram. This is useful and will differ if you specify a value for **nbins**.

Works cited: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html

Comment: The documentation only says that the input vector `x` specifies the centers of the bins but doesn't define what "bin locations" `xout` are exactly. Admittedly, they're likely to also define bin centers.

Comment: I agree. The documentation says only "bin locations", which is ambiguous. But, in any case, I believe the answer is correct.